# MS-ProjectServer 2003. Can MS-Project 2007 be used as client?

Tags: microsoft-project

Does anybody know if MS-Project 2007 can be used as client to a ProjectSever 2003 installation?
We have an existing setup with Project-Pro 2003 clients on XP.
For our newer Win7 machines the standard Project is 2007.
Will this work ? Or would we have to install Project 2003 Pro on the Win7 machines?
(Rather not do that, as the rest of Office on the Win7 machines will be 2007.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is a long dead question, but in case it comes up for anyone's search:

No, Project Pro 2007 can not be used with Project Server 2003. Under certain circumstances (Backward Compatibility Mode is enabled) Project Pro 2007 can act as a client for Project Server 2010, but other than that, the client and server version must match.

Comment: Thanks Jamie. We did go the "install 2003 route" and I never got around to testing the 2007/2003 mix. But it is good to know for the future that this is not an option. It means I need to make sure the next version (if ProjectServer is used at all) is going to be 2010.